# How to remove blank lines between menus with hyperlink under navbarMenu?

Tags: r, shiny

I'd like to add some menus with hyperlinks under navbarMenu in R shiny. Below is an example script:

**ui.r**

```
library(shiny)
ui <- navbarPage(
  "AppName",
  tabPanel(
    title = "File"
  ),
  tabPanel(
    title = "Analysis"
  ),
  navbarMenu(
    "Help",
    tabPanel(
      tags$a(href = "https://www.google.com/", "Tutorial", target = "_blank")
    ),
    tabPanel(
      tags$a(href = "https://www.google.com/", "Report Bug", target = "_blank")
    ),
    tabPanel(
      "Citation",
      tags$p("please cite:")
    )
  )

)
```

**server.R**

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}
```

However, there are two blank lines as shown below:

[image]

I searched for this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48307652/display-list-of-downloads-in-navbarmenu-in-shiny), but couldn't find an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(shiny)

js <- "
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.navbar .container-fluid .navbar-nav .dropdown .dropdown-menu').prepend(
        '<li><a href=\"https://www.google.com\" target=\"_blank\">Tutorial</a></li>',
        '<li><a href=\"https://www.google.com\" target=\"_blank\">Report Bug</a></li>');
});
"

ui <- tagList(
    tags$script(HTML(js)),
    navbarPage(
    "AppName",
    tabPanel(
        title = "File"
    ),
    tabPanel(
        title = "Analysis"
    ),
    navbarMenu(
        "Help",
        tabPanel(
            "Citation",
            tags$p("please cite:")
        )
    )
    
))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Good job, thanks, Jan!

Answer (score 0):

Using custom HTML with `tags$li` and `tags$a` for embedding direct links in the dropdown.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- navbarPage(
  "AppName",
  tabPanel(
    title = "File"
  ),
  tabPanel(
    title = "Analysis"
  ),
  navbarMenu(
    "Help",
    tags$li(class = "dropdown-header", "Resources"),
    tags$li(tags$a(href = "https://www.google.com/", "Tutorial", target = "_blank", "Tutorial")),
    tags$li(tags$a(href = "https://www.google.com/", "Report Bug", target = "_blank", "Report Bug")),
    tags$li(class = "divider"),
    tags$li(class = "dropdown-header", "More"),
    tags$li(tags$p("Please cite:"))
    # If you want to include a specific citation directly in the dropdown, it gets a bit more tricky,
    # as the standard dropdown menu isn't designed for complex content.
    # A straightforward workaround is to put your citation text as a tooltip or modal trigger if it's too long.
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

edit:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- navbarPage(
  "AppName",
  tabPanel("File"),
  tabPanel("Analysis"),
  # Adding custom HTML for direct links in the navbar
  tags$li(class = "nav-item", tags$a(href = "https://www.google.com/", "Tutorial", class = "nav-link", target = "_blank")),
  tags$li(class = "nav-item", tags$a(href = "https://www.google.com/", "Report Bug", class = "nav-link", target = "_blank"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but this solution doesn't align with my preferences. I would like to have direct hyperlinks instead of using drop-down menus.

Comment: Understandable, check the edited code.

Comment: Hi @ASITYA, thanks for the updates, however, the updated ones are still not my preferences.